# Reasons why division by zero is not infinity or it is infinity.

Tags: limits, divisibility

So, here is a fundamental question, division by zero is undefined, there are some ways to prove this. Lets take the following limit

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{1}{x} = +\infty $$

but

$$\lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{1}{x} = -\infty $$

So the limit does not exist, thus division by zero is undefined.

But let's go way more basic. What is division? Division can be though of as a number of succesive substractions until you reach zero or before you hit a negative number.

Say you want to divide 8/3, you start by

$$8-3 = 5$$

Do it once more

$$5-3 = 2$$

And then you stop, because if you substract 2-3 = -1 and we said we were going to stop at zero or before it got negative.

So how many substractions did we had to perform before we reached zero or a negative number? 2 of them, what number was left after the last substraction? also 2, so 8/3 is 2 with a remainder of 2. Simple as that.

Let's do the same but now lets divide 8/0

So we start

$$8-0=8$$

One more time

$$8-0 = 8$$

and again...

$$8 - 0 = 8$$

Do you see were I am going with this? So we can say, ok, substracting zero from eight will never reach zero so division by zero is not defined, or we can go crazy and count the number of times we can keep doing this and the result is infinity, so could we say that 8/0 is infinity with a remainder of 8?

Comment: With the same argument, you "can also say that" $8/0$ is $3$ with a remainder of $8$.

Comment: Infinity is not a number. Note that even though $\lim_{x \to 0} 1/|x| = +\infty$, in common parlance, this limit does not exist, and writing that it equals $+\infty$ just gives a description of why the limit fails to exist.

Comment: @player3236 yes, but 3 would mean that you 'stopped' at 3 substractions, you can't stop until you hit zero according to the rules I mentioned, so the more sensible answer is 'why stop?' in which case the answer is infinity with a remainder of 8.

Comment: Spontaneously, I see the issue that the remainder is always smaller than the divisor, this is the case for the simple case but not for the one with dividing by zero. Division becomes way less intuitive in this regard and possibly breaks in another location.

Comment: This post shows effort and thoughtful reasoning. Why are people downvoting it?

Comment: @DavidMitra apparently its such a given and sensible topic that people don't want to hear about it

Comment: No need to be sarcastic about it. Some people are just tired of hearing about $n$ divided by $0$ again. This appears quite often on MSE.

Comment: Maybe it can be found little strange that you consider fine reaching `+∞` and having reminder as result of division. In neither of your examples you showed division. There latter example is read _"There exist infinity steps for substitution of division `8` by `0` with substraction."_. Step count surely grows towards `+∞`. Every step you get substractible remainder. So this implies for outcome `+∞` no remainder or you have to stop at some number. But you still have to prove by math lang that infinite steps = outcome which you **just said**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are four different counter-examples/arguments to disprove what you said:

---

#### $1:$

Division by $0$ is literally impossible and you cannot use this operation. Why? Suppose $\frac{n}{0}=k$. This would result in $n=0$, which is a contradiction (I don't even want to talk about why $\frac{0}{0}$ doesn't exist)

---

#### $2:$

AssuminG you can indeed work with $\frac{k}{0}$, by the same algorithm, you could say that for any $n$, $8$ divided by $0$ is $n$ with a remainder of $8$, thus leading in a contradiction.

Why is this a contradiction? Well (in our case), division is a bijection, a function, from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ (actually from $\mathbb{N^*}$ but we assume dividing by $0$ is possible) and if $\frac{k}{0}$ could take multiple values, this would defeat the purpose of a function.

Remember, division was first and then people found out we cannot divide by $0$

---

#### $3:$

The algorithm you defined is not at all division. It is finding the integer part of $\frac{m}{n}$ where $m,n>0$. Just to put in evidence another flaw of your so called division, look at this:

What is $\frac{8}{-1}$? (it is $-8$)

Well $8-(-1)=9$. We need to do it again... $9-(-1)=10$ uh we need to do it again... $10-(-1)=11$ oh wait we never reach a negative number!

So does this imply that $-8=\frac{8}{-1}=+\infty$?

---

Just as another observation, people often belive that division is some sort of subtraction and multiplication is some sort of adittion. This is wrong, exactly because of $0$ (which led to people struggling with this in the ancient time), because of negative numbers, because of irrational numbers, because of complex numbers etc.

---

#### $4:$

Assuming you still belive in division by $0$, you don't care that division is a bijection and you still belive in your algorithm, then take a look at this:

$$\frac{1}{0}=\infty=\frac{2}{0}\Rightarrow\frac{1}{0}=\frac{2}{0}\Rightarrow\frac{1}{0}\cdot 0=\frac{2}{0}\cdot 0\Rightarrow 1=2$$

I am sorry if at this points your eyes are bleeding, reader

Comment: @user799688 To your point no. 3, a refined logic could be "How many times should the denominator be subtracted from the numerator to reach zero?" Consider 8 / (-1). -1 needs to be subtracted -8 times from 8 to reach zero. This is the same as adding (-1) 8 times to 8.
Hence, -8 would be the result of the division operation.
Let me know if this leads to consistency.

Answer (score -1):

You can't *prove* that division by zero is undefined. It's not defined, there is nothing to prove.

For real numbers, addition and multiplication are defined for all pairs of numbers. Subtraction is defined by solving an equation that can be easily solved for all pairs of numbers. Division is *defined* by solving an equation that can be easily solved for all pairs x, y of numbers where y ≠ 0.

You can give arguments why it is reasonable not to define division by zero, but the fact is that it is not defined.

We could easily define division by zero: We could just say that x / y := x whenever y = 0. It's just that many mathematical theorems that specify "... if division is defined" would need to be changed to "... if the divisor is not zero".